# create pdf from asp.net page view

Tags: itext

I try to create a pdf file from html page view with itextsharp.

This code block works but, I get html code string from url and I want to give this string to be converted. So I can convert any site view to pdf by giving url to function. Thanks..

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string htmlText = wc.DownloadString("http://");

this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLWorker is buggy and has been discontinued, in favor of XMLWorker.

- The project page : http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/
- The demo page : http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/
- The documentation : http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html

Even though the documentation refers to the Java version, adapting the examples to iTextSharp should be straightforward.